# How to read macOS desktop file in cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to make cocoa app execute .sh file or other Operation,
this my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self cmd:@"cd Desktop;ls;"]);
}

- (NSString *)cmd:(NSString *)cmd
{
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/bash"];
    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c", cmd, nil];
    [task setArguments: arguments];
    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];
    NSFileHandle *file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
    [task launch];
    NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

but log error：

```
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

how to do that?I search about macOS permit,Do I need use [SMJobBless](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandbox applications aren't allowed to read outside the application folder. So in order for your script to work you need to turn off Sandbox.

Also you need to change the path like Sangram S. mentioned or set the current directory to the home folder:

```
[task setCurrentDirectoryPath:NSHomeDirectory()];
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[self cmd:@"cd Desktop;ls;"]);
```

with

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self cmd:@"cd ~/Desktop; ls;"]);
```

Comment: thank,but not work,log error:`ls: .: Operation not permitted`